# Why can't Qt distinguish the hyphen and the minus key?

Tags: qt, qt5, keypress

I'm reviewing some part of a project written with Qt:

```
void Editor::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    int key = event->key();

    switch (key) {
    case Qt::Key_Tab:
...
```

I've put a breakpoint at `int key = event->key()`.

Now, I've notice that pressing the minus "-" on the keypad shows me in debug:

```
Pressed 'Minus' (key:45 vKey:65453)
Qt::Key_Minus (0x002d)
```

Then, pressing "-" (the hyphen on the hyphen/underscore key gives me:

```
Pressed 'Minus' (key:45 vKey:45)"
Qt::Key_Minus (0x002d)
1439241440
```

So they are definitely detected as different (judging from this "vKey" number) but the event is the same: "Key_Minus".

Why can't I get the "Key_hyphen" event? How could I solve this (maybe using this "vKey" number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
event->nativeVirtualKey();
```

and

```
event->nativeScanCode();
```

Comment: Yes, it allows to get this "vkey". But do you know the answer to the first part of my question ("Why can't I get the "Key_hyphen" event?")

Comment: There is a comment in `qshortcutmap.cpp` that goes like: Basically the same function as QKeySequence::matches(const QKeySequence &seq) const only that is specially handles Key_hyphen as Key_Minus, as people mix these up all the time and they conceptually the same. Does that help?
`

Comment: Note: Unicode U+00AD (Soft hyphen) Unicode U+002D (Minus) are different things.